# Identifying words in two texts (if statement in for loop)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

This is my first time posting a question. I am fairly new to programming and very new to javascript. I have searched the threads for a solution to my problem but I still cant figure it out. I am have a text (text2) that is heavily influenced by another text (text1). I have an array of all words in text1 and I want to loop over that array and if the word is in both texts I want to display it on my webpage in a different color.

Here is what I have:

```
var text1 = ["جهيم"، "سجين"، "الكتاب"];         
var text2 = ["الله قد انزل الكتاب فيه تبيان كل شئ رحمة وبشرى على الحق بالحق على العالمين جميعا"]        

for (i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {            
   if (i in text2) {                
      document.write("<span class="color">"+ text2[i]+"</span>");           
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it would really help if you could change text1 and text2 to english in your example, so that others can easily figure out what is required. Language barrier is making it harder to grasp the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
for (i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {            
   if (text2.indexOf(text1[i]) > -1) {                
      document.write("<span class="color">"+ text1[i]+"</span>");           
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.indexOf` to check whether or not `text2[j]` contains `text1[i]`, notes here that you have two different **indexes**, because you have two different arrays

```
var text1 = ["جهيم", "سجين", "الكتاب"];
var text2 = ["الله قد انزل الكتاب فيه تبيان كل شئ رحمة وبشرى على الحق بالحق على العالمين جميعا"];

for (var i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < text2.length; j++) {
       if (text2[j].indexOf(text1[i]) > -1) {                
          document.write("<span class='color'>"+ text2[j]+"</span>");
       }
    }
}
```

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zayocoyiwa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery $inArray:

```
 for (i=0; i< text1.length; i++){
      if($.inArray(text1[i], text2)!=-1){
        document.write("<span class="color">"+ text1[i]+"</span>"); 
      }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split)** and **[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace)** methods, with no need to use any array for the words in `text1`, and `text1` and `text2` should be strings:

```
var text1 = "جهيم سجين الكتاب";         
var text2 = "الله قد انزل الكتاب فيه تبيان كل شئ رحمة وبشرى على الحق بالحق على العالمين جميعا";

for (var word in text2.split(" ")){
     if(text1.includes(word)){
         text2.replace(word, "<span class=\"color\">"+word+"</span>");
     }
}
```

And in the `text2` you will have the words found in both `text1` and `text2` colored.

**EDIT:**

And if you want to use `text1` as an array:

```
var text1 = ["جهيم"، "سجين"، "الكتاب"]; 
for (var word in text2.split(" ")){
     if(text1.includes(word)){
         text2.replace(word, "<span class=\"color\">"+word+"</span>");   
     }
}
```

Because in Javascript both **Strings** and **Arrays** have the `includes()` method.